# Alternative to exec in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that runs in the background to posts pictures to different websites. After a picture is uploaded, it will call a script to run like this:

```
$user_id = "77";
exec("/usr/bin/php5 upload_auto.php?user_id=$user_id");
```

And after calling it, it runs a code like this:

```
<?php
$the_picture_id_to_check = $_GET['user_id'];
mysql_connect("localhost","********", "********") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(myflashp_pictures) or die (mysql_error());
require_once('connect/twitter_files/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('connect/twitter_files/config.php');

?>

<!--- Upload Tumblr --->

<?php
$result_tumblr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM upload_tumblr WHERE user_id=$the_picture_id_to_check"); 
$num_rows_find = mysql_num_rows($result_tumblr);
while($row_tumblr=mysql_fetch_array($result_tumblr)){

// Get Username
$the_id = "".$row_tumblr['id']."";
$picture_id = "".$row_tumblr['picture_id']."";
$picture_url = "".$row_tumblr['picture_url']."";
$user_id = "".$row_tumblr['user_id']."";
$caption = "".$row_tumblr['caption']."";
$album_id = "".$row_tumblr['album_id']."";

// Authorization info
$monday_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photo_albums WHERE id='$album_id'");
$monday_query_row=mysql_fetch_array($monday_result);
$tumblr_id = $monday_query_row['tumblr_id']; 

$monday_result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM connections_tumblr WHERE id='$tumblr_id'");
$monday_query_row2 = mysql_fetch_array($monday_result2);
$tumblr_email = $monday_query_row2['email']; 
$tumblr_password = $monday_query_row2['password']; 

// Prepare POST request
$request_data = http_build_query(
array(
    'email'             => $tumblr_email,
    'password'          => $tumblr_password,
    'type'              => 'photo',
    'source'            => $picture_url,
    'caption'           => $caption,
    'generator'         => 'FlashPics iPhone App'
)
);

// Send the POST request (with cURL)
$c = curl_init('http://www.tumblr.com/api/write');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_data);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($c);
$status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($c);

// Check for success
if ($status == 201) {
mysql_query("UPDATE pictures SET tumblr_id='$result' WHERE id='$picture_id'");
echo "Success! The new Tumblr post ID is $result.<br>\n";
mysql_query("DELETE FROM upload_tumblr WHERE id='$the_id'");
} else if ($status == 403) {
echo 'Bad email or password for Tumblr.';
} else if ($status == 400) {
echo "Error ($status): $result\n";
mysql_query("DELETE FROM upload_tumblr WHERE id='$the_id'");
} else {
echo "Error ($status): $result\n";
}

}

if ($num_rows_find == 0) {
echo "There's nothing to post to Tumblr.";
}

?>

<br /><br />



<!--- Upload Email --->

<?php

include_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$result_email = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM upload_email WHERE status='processing' AND user_id='$the_picture_id_to_check'"); 
$num_rows_find = mysql_num_rows($result_email);
mysql_query("UPDATE upload_email SET status='$num_rows_find' WHERE id='1'");
while($row_email=mysql_fetch_array($result_email)){

// Get Username
$to = "".$row_email['email']."";


$get_info_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$row_email['user_id']."'");
$get_info_query_row = mysql_fetch_array($get_info_result);
$get_username = $get_info_query_row['username'];
$get_first_name = $get_info_query_row['first_name'];
$get_last_name = $get_info_query_row['last_name']; 

$get_info_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE id='".$row_email['picture_id']."'");
$get_info_query_row = mysql_fetch_array($get_info_result);
$get_caption = $get_info_query_row['caption'];
$get_picture_url = $get_info_query_row['long_url'];
$get_short_string = $get_info_query_row['short_string'];

if ($get_caption == "") {
$get_caption = "I have shared a FlashPic with you.";
}


$mail             = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From       = "share@myflashpics.com";
$mail->FromName   = "FlashPics";
$mail->Subject    = "$get_first_name $get_last_name has shared a FlashPic with you.";

$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body = "
<html><body style='margin: 0px; padding: 0px;'>
<div style='padding: 15px; width: 480px; font-family: Helvetica; margin: 10px; border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;'>
<div style='font-weight: bolder; font-size: 32px; margin: 8px 0px 20px 0px;'><font color='#353535'>Flash</font><font color='#f8bc49'>Pics</font></div>

<div style='font-size: 20px; color: #353535; font-weight: normal; text-transform: lowercase;'>$get_username</div>

<div style='margin-top: 15px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px;'>$get_caption<br>
<br>
<img src=$get_picture_url width='480'>
<br><br>
<a href='http://myflashpics.com/picture/$get_short_string' style='color: #000000; text-decoration: underline;'>view full size image</a><br>
<br>
Sincerely,<br>
The FlashPics Team</div>

</div>
</body></html>";

$mail->AltBody    = "$get_username
$get_caption

http://myflashpics.com/picture/".$row_email['picture_id']."

Yours Truly,
The FlashPics Team";


$the_id = "".$row_email['id']."";

$pieces = explode(", ", "$to");

$one = $pieces['0'];
$two = $pieces['1']; 
$three = $pieces['2']; 
$four = $pieces['3']; 
$five = $pieces['4']; 

if ($one != "") {
$mail->AddBCC("$one");
}
if ($two != "") {
$mail->AddBCC("$two");
}
if ($three != "") {
$mail->AddBCC("$three");
}
if ($four != "") {
$mail->AddBCC("$four");
}
if ($five != "") {
$mail->AddBCC("$five");
}

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Failed sending email to <b> $one, $two, $three, $four, $five</b>." . $mail->ErrorInfo;
mysql_query("UPDATE upload_email SET status='error' WHERE id='$the_id'");
} else {
echo "Sent email to <b> ".$row_email['email']."</b> successfully.<br>";
mysql_query("UPDATE upload_email SET status='sent' WHERE id='$the_id'");
}

}

if ($num_rows_find == 0) {
echo "There are no pictures to email out.";
}

?>
```

So basically only certain parts will work (I didn't post all my code). I just posted what wasn't working. **But if I run it manually from the browser, all parts working**. If you want to see my php_info, I have it [here](http://myflashpics.com/info.php).

Thanks in advance,
Coulton

*PS: By "Not Working", I mean that nothing happens and I see no errors*

Comment: any error message? you only post code, not problem(s).

Comment: not working? need a bit more than that!

Comment: You guys don't get it.  It isn't working.

Comment: @ k to the z i assume that's sarcasm

Comment: @silent There are no errors. At least its not outputting any... Also the "It isn't working" literally means "It isn't working". Nothing happens with those two script. However if I run it manually from the browser, it works.

Comment: you could add some basic error checking. or hire a psychic

Comment: @Dagon: Basic error checking? I like that on better. haha.

Comment: @Kevin Hikaru Evans: Where do you see a potential SQL injection?

Comment: call it from the command line with a user id then at least you will see errors. otherwise they will have to be logged as its running background you cant expect to see them on the screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From comment thread, I assume the `exec` is not working.

Try to:

1. change path file to absolute path:
2. also, since it's meant to run on shell, change parameter to what shell script work:

   ```
   exec("/usr/bin/php5 /path/to/whatever/your/file/is/upload_auto.php $user_id");
   ```

**NOTE**

See that I change your parameter from:

```
upload_auto.php?user_id=$user_id
```

to

```
upload_auto.php $user_id
```

That how shell script work.

In order to get that parameter, you should use [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php):

```
$user_id = $argv[1];
```

Or, to make it able to run on both browser and shell, change it to:

```
$user_id = (php_sapi_name() == 'cli' && empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) ? $argv[1] : $_GET['user_id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the php script from command line but you are trying to get the value  from $_GET variable. It's not going to work. 
Try to fetch the value from argv[1]. 
$the_picture_id_to_check = argv[1];

Comment: Will I use the same code in to call it? Can you please post some example code, new to this kind of stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and that was the problem. However someone beat ya to it.. sorry.